# Min-Width, Horizontal Row, Percentage Widths Prioritization

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some html for two graphs that looks like this:

```
<div style="width:90%;margin:auto;">
    <div style="width:48%;height:100%;min-width:350px;float:left;margin:auto;"></div>
    <div style="width:48%;height:100%;min-width:350px;float:left;margin:auto;"></div>
</div>
```

It does the following: if the graphs fit, (the container is bigger than 700/0.9px) the graphs appear side by side. Great! And if the container's too small, they go to separate lines. Great! But they each only take up 48% on those separate lines, which is not what I want. What I'd like is this:

```
<div style="width:90%;margin:auto;">
    <div style="width:90%;height:100%;min-width:350px;float:left;margin:1%/auto;PRIORITIZE HORIZONTAL FIT;"></div>
    <div style="width:90%;height:100%;min-width:350px;float:left;margin:1%/auto;PRIORITIZE HORIZONTAL FIT;"></div>
</div>
```

So that they took up 90% of the div's width if they were on separate rows, but 48% if they're on the same row. I don't know the prioritize horizontal fit command, or how to do the margins conditionally, but it seems like this should be possible in HTML.

I could flesh out the conditional in javascript, `if (document.getElementById('divID').scrollwidth>700)`, but I don't want to use inner.HTML (I'm getting outputs from my stats program as svgs, and getting rid of the carriage returns or making each line a string to concatenate is also a hassle. But surely there has to be a way to do this in HTML.

It should look like:

```
| |----------1----------| |----------2----------| |
```

or

```
| |-----1-----| |-----2-----| |
```

or

```
| |-------1-------| |
| |-------2-------| |
```

depending on the width of the window. I'm missing something easy, right?!

Comment: uhmm tried bootstrap?

Comment: Look into flex box layouts and/or CSS media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to the rescue! Try resizing the outer box:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 150px; /* shrunk from 350 for the snippet */
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 1%;
}

/* the rest is just for this example */
.red{background:maroon;border:3px solid red;}
.blue{background:navy;border:3px solid blue;}
#container{border:3px dotted black;resize:horizontal;overflow:hidden;}
.box{height:50px;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
</div>
```

[`display: flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-2) defines a block flex container. [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-4) lets the boxes wrap onto two lines. [`justify-content: center`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-6) centers the boxes within their container. [`flex: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) is shorthand for [`flex-grow: 1`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-10) (lets the boxes grow equally), [`flex-shrink: 1`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-11) (lets the boxes shrink equally, to their `min-width`), [`flex-basis: 0`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-12) (distribute extra space independently of the boxes' content).

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! What if I wanted them to wrap at a different width than my min-width (say 400px to wrap, min-width of 300px)?

Comment: Oh, that appears to be flex-basis. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

OR you can do it using bootstrap.
using inline class is not recommended.

```css
.red {
  background-color: #a10909;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #093fa1;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="box red">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="box blue">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```